# How to join two streams without time window in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am getting data from two streams. I want to join these two streams based on a key. For example, consider two streams. Data in stream A can come first. Sometimes data in stream B can come first. The joining data in the streams can come at any time. Because of this nature, I can't use a windowed join. Is it possible to join two unbounded streams in flink?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a non-windowed Join will behave as you want: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#regular-joins

If you are using the `DataStream API` instead of the `SQL API`, a `CoFlatMap` operator implementing a shared state that keeps the elements from both sides and joins them when there is an update, would allow you to implement this behavior as well.

Take into account that this requires keeping both sides in state forever, which can make grow your state infinitely.

The note in the Flink SQL documentation advises looking at setting a state TTL:  https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-state-ttl. That would be the DataStream equivalent: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl The problem is that if some records in the state expire and there is an update that would require to be joined with the expired element, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: Depending on the join semantics you want, a versioned (or temporal) join might be prefered, since it doesn't have to keep all of the input rows in state forever.